# Why my design view of .xml of android studio is blank?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I have updated my android studio 2.3.3 to 3.0, now I'm facing this problem. I can't see design view thought everything else work well. This message is shown when I try to view it, **"IDE error"**

I have tried these steps :

1. Make project
2. Clean Project
3. Restart Android Studio.

   Not working!
   [image: See below]

Comment: post the text xml code

Comment: Put your xml code.

Comment: the code isn't modified

Comment: i have tried adding or removing the xml code, not worked.

Comment: An unfortunate thing of the design mode is that it won't work for everything so either the xml no longer works with it or you've encountered a bug.

Comment: problem solved. I just updated my SDK tools.